# Trouble with strcpy/appending strings

Tags: c++

So I'm trying to make a name changer for a game. The offset that represents the gamertag is 0x838BA824; I'm trying to make a loop, that changes the color of the name like in a rainbow. So when im enabling the "rainbow"-gamertag i do this:

```
LastName = (char*)0x838BA824;//char *LastName;
Rainbow = !Rainbow;//a boolean used to toggle
```

Then in a hook/loop i do this:

```
if(Rainbow)//the toggle boolean
{
    printf("LastName: %s\n", LastName);
    peep++;//int peep;
    if(peep >= 8)
        peep = 0;
    switch(peep)
    {
        case 0:
            printf("0\n");
            Buffer += "^0";//std::string buffer || ^0-9 are the colorcodes for that game, so here it adds the color
            Buffer += LastName;//then it adds the name
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());//then it sets the string with the color
            Buffer = "";//it clears the Buffer
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 1:
            printf("1\n");
            Buffer += "^1";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 2:
            printf("2\n");
            Buffer += "^2";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 3:
            printf("3\n");
            Buffer += "^3";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 4:
            printf("4\n");
            Buffer += "^4";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 5:
            printf("5\n");
            Buffer += "^5";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 6:
            printf("6\n");
            Buffer += "^6";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
        case 7:
            printf("7\n");
            Buffer += "^7";
            Buffer += LastName;
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
            strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
            Buffer = "";
            printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT: i could also just call this in the hook(same result -.-)

```
void changeName()
{
    printf("LastName: %s\n", LastName);
    peep++;
    if(peep >= 8)
        peep = 0;
    printf("%i\n", peep);
    Buffer += va("^%i", peep);
    Buffer += LastName;
    printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
    strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
    Buffer = "";
    printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
}
```

Till now everything seemed to be fine for me, so i tested it and i got that as output in my console:

```
LastName: Test
1
Buffer: ^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
0
Buffer: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: ^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
1
Buffer: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
Buffer: 
LastName: ^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
2
Buffer: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
Buffer: 
LastName: ^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
3
Buffer: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
Buffer: 
LastName: ^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
4
Buffer: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1
Buffer: 
LastName: ^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
5
Buffer: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
Buffer: 
LastName: ^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
6
Buffer: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
Buffer: 
LastName: ^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
7
Buffer: ^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5^4^3^2^1^0^7^6^5
Buffer:
```

anyone knows why it doesnt clears buffer(or why it also sets lastname to the buffer) correctly or why this happens?
normally the output should look like this, if its correct:

```
LastName: Test
1
Buffer: ^1Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
2
Buffer: ^2Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
3
Buffer: ^3Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
4
Buffer: ^4Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
5
Buffer: ^5Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
6
Buffer: ^6Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
7
Buffer: ^7Test
Buffer: 
LastName: Test
```

Comment: Using hardcoded addresses lots suspect. Also why are you using `printf`?

Comment: its a xbox game and it prints into a console that comes with the xbox sdk

Comment: You have 7 lines of repeated blocks of code with the only difference being a number.  A good programmer knows how to detect patterns and instead writes one block of code.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie i also tried it "not hardcoded" where it only calls one void each case with different parameters and same result, i could post that too if u want^^ + added to OP

Comment: If you look at what `LastName` is every time you enter the function, it's set to whatever you copied to the hardcoded memory address. ie: The first time you change `LastName` from `Test` to `^1Test`. The second time you change `LastName` from `^1Test` to `^2^1Test`. You'll need to strip off the control character you added in the last run

Comment: @SteveLorimer yes, i saw that. i though strcpy only writes the second parameter to the first one, so i dont see why lastname should change at all through this process...

Comment: @SyxDuLappen [See here](http://ideone.com/wmN1jv)

Comment: @SyxDuLappen where is `LastName` coming from? If it's provided by the API then it's likely copying it from the hardcoded memory address. That is, whatever you copy to the address is what `LastName` will be the next time around

Comment: @SteveLorimer hmm i dont think so, i initialize it outside of the loop as a char*

Comment: Where and how is `Buffer` declared and defined?

Comment: @SyxDuLappen then you haven't provided enough information to show where the problem is. The problem is not in your loop, it's outside.

Comment: @mvidelgauz Buffer is defined outside the loop as a std::string

Comment: @SteveLorimer no i provided anything where LastName, Buffer is used, except the initialization of them, which is std::string Buffer;
char *LastName;

Comment: given the code you've shown `Buffer = "^<number>";` should hide your problem, but `Buffer = "";` should have handled that, so somewhere outside the provided code something is trampling over `Buffer` and that is a much more insidious problem.

Comment: So you initialise `char* LastName = (char*)0x838BA824;`? Then you change what's pointed to at `0x838BA824`, then you initialise `char* LastName = (char*)0x838BA824;` the next time? Surprise! You just changes what's pointed to at `0x838BA824`, so the next time around you're getting the previous control character

Comment: @SteveLorimer no your code example worked for me now, and its only initialized once, thats why i was confused

Answer (score 2, accepted):

LastName is a pointer to 0x838BA824, which is the address you're writing to with strcpy.

Every time you're updating the gamertag, you're re-reading the name from LastName, so you're getting back what you put in it on the last iteration.

There are two ways I can suggest to correct this:

1) initialise a std::string to LastName when you first enable it, then do not re-read LastName afterwards

```
char *LastNamePtr = (char*)0x838BA824;
std::string LastNameString(LastNamePtr);
Rainbow = true;

// ...

if (Rainbow) {
    peep = (peep + 1) & 7;
    std::string Buffer = "^" + std::to_string(peep) + LastNameString;
    strcpy(LastNamePtr, Buffer.c_str());
}
```

or 2) detect the '^' character when you re-read the string, and if so, change the number instead of adding the '^' and number

```
char *LastNamePtr = (char*)0x838BA824;
Rainbow = true;

// ...

if (Rainbow) {
    peep = (peep + 1) & 7;
    if (LastNamePtr[0] == '^') { // check first character of string
        LastNamePtr[1] = peep + '0'; // update second character of string
    } else {
        std::string Buffer = "^" + std::to_string(peep) + std::string(LastNamePtr);
        strcpy(LastNamePtr, Buffer.c_str());
    }
}
```

In either case note the `peep = (peep + 1) & 7` is a more consise way of writing

```
peep++;
if (peep >= 8)
    peep = 0;
```

and I've used `std::to_string` and `peep + '0'` to get a digit from an int without using a switch.

Answer (score 2):

As I mentioned in the comments, it looks like you initialise `char* LastName = (char*)0x838BA824;` before entering the function.

Then you change what's pointed to at `0x838BA824`

```
strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
```

The next time around, when you initialise `char* LastName = (char*)0x838BA824;` you pick up the changes you made the first time.

Every time you repeat this you'll pick up the changes from the previous runs.

The fix is to **strip off the control characters first**.

```
if(Rainbow)
{
    printf("LastName: %s\n", LastName);

    // clear off the previous control characters if they are there
    if (LastName[0] == '^' && std::isdigit(LastName[1]))
        LastName = LastName.substr(2)

    if(++peep >= 8)
        peep = 0;

    printf("%d\n", peep);

    Buffer = "^";
    Buffer += std::to_string(peep);
    Buffer += LastName;

    printf("Buffer: %s\n", Buffer.c_str());
    strcpy((char*)0x838BA824, Buffer.c_str());
}
```